# $\frac{dy}{dx}=\cot(x)[\frac{\sin(x)}{y}-\frac{y}{2}]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hello fellow Mathematicians , I am stuck with this problem here. 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\cot(x)[\frac{\sin(x)}{y}-\frac{y}{2}]$$
I did open bracket and it became
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\cos(x)}{y}-\frac{ycot(x)}{2}$$
but now there is doses't seem to any way to separate $x$ and $y$ can you give me some hints here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $y^2=t$
Differ. wrt $x$ , you get $2y\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dt}{dx}$
now put $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in above, and you get Linear Form